# asp.net show confirm prompt at page load event (no button click)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to show a prompt similar to the one below, as soon as when the user arrives on a page (from a clicking a link from an email). Something similar to a page load event. I am currently doing this by adding an onclick event on a button and somehow having the button clicked via code rather than manual click. That would have been ideal for me although I cant get it to work. I would also like enable the prompt on a specific querystring... I have tried something similar to the below with no luck so far... cant get the buttonclick event to fire on page load thus not showing the prompt. The event doesn't fire up and it only does when I manually click the button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0frU.png

```js
  function confirmReset() {
            $(document).ready(function() { $('#mybutton').click(); });
        }
```

```html
   If Convert.ToByte(Request.QueryString("_r$")) = 1 Then     
        mybutton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('WARNING! You are about to delete all data .\n\n DO YOU REALLY WANT TO DO THIS?')")
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "a key", "<script type=""text/javascript"">window.onload =  $(function () { confirmReset() });""</script>")
end if
```

Comment: Why would you want to ruin the experience for the visitors? This is a very bad practice and many browser plugins will block it anyway.

Comment: So they are being redirected to a particular page after selecting a delete option, and this page automatically performs the delete, so you want to give them a warning?  It does seem like an unusual situation, but if that's the case, you could just display the warning on the page and only show delete and cancel buttons?  Otherwise, wouldn't you just put your confirm script right in the  $(document).ready(function() {} ) ?

Comment: you are both right... i was asked to provide a quick work around with this kind of behaviour but thanks to both of you i will try implement something more fancy by using a modal window or something similar... thanks again!